# code wars battle ship damaged or sunk - python

Tags: python, recursion

I am unsure what is causing my solution to the following kata to fail.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/battle-ships-sunk-damaged-or-not-touched/train/python

I believe that if I could view the random test cases or test case 3 that I could debug it easily. However, the inputs for these test cases are not available.

Here is the code for my solution, it does not fail because of diagonal ships but occasionally missing a hit altogether.

```
def damaged_or_sunk(board, attacks):
# reverse board rows
board = board[::-1]
# function state variables 
attack_count = 0
ship_lengths, hits = {}, []

# return values stored in dict
return_hash = {"sunk" : 0,
               "damaged" : 0,
               "not_touched" : 0,
               "points" : 0}

# check board
for attack in attacks:
    attack_count += 1
    attack_index = (attack[0] - 1, attack[1] - 1)
    for row in board:    
        for column in row:  
            if column != 0:
                if attack_count == 1: 
                    if column in ship_lengths:   
                        ship_lengths[column] += 1
                    else:
                        ship_lengths[column] = 1
                ship_index = (row.index(column), board.index(row))
                if ship_index == attack_index:
                    hits.append(column)
                if len(hits) >= len(attacks):
                    break

# catagorize hits     
for ship in ship_lengths.keys():
    if hits.count(ship) == ship_lengths[ship]:
        return_hash["sunk"] += 1
    elif ship not in hits:
        return_hash["not_touched"] += 1
    else: 
        return_hash["damaged"] += 1

# calculate points
for return_val in return_hash.keys():
    if return_val == "sunk":
        return_hash["points"] += return_hash["sunk"]
    elif return_val == "damaged":
        return_hash["points"] += (return_hash["damaged"] / 2)
    elif return_val == "not_touched":
        return_hash["points"] -= return_hash["not_touched"]

return return_hash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I love this problem! Code Wars Kata are a LOT of fun, especially when you figure them out on you own ;)

That said, you are stuck and I am going to help you out; but instead of copy-pasting my solution in here, I'm going to tell you what I did and let you learn from it at your own pace.

Let's take a look at just one of the test cases - Main Game 3 - in a little more detail. You mentioned that the inputs for the test cases were not available, but adding

```
print(board)
print(attacks)
```

to the top of our function tells us everything we need to know. Here is the game board:

```
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 2 0
0 2 0
```

and here are our attack points:

```
[3, 4], [2, 1], [2, 2]
```

Now for a description of what I did to solve this problem (PLEASE do not feel like you have to do things this way, you are MORE than welcome to take what I've told you and continue working on the problem without reading further).

First thing I did was loop through both rows and columns and made a dictionary containing every located ship, their location, and that cell's hit/miss status (0 for "not hit" and 1 for "hit"). I see this is something you are trying to do with ship_lengths (or at least I think that's what your trying to do), but you've made it more complicated by splitting up the data. By building a dictionary, I can keep everything in one place (the ship number, its location, and it hits); Here is what my dictionary looks like using this example:

```
{'1': [[3, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0]], '2': [[2, 1, 0], [2, 2, 0]]}
```

After this I loop through my attacks list and compare it to every element in my dictionary, if the X values and the Y values line up, I change that third value from a 0 to a 1 (Hit!).

When I'm done looping through that attacks list I go back through my dictionary and looks for "hits" and "sinks", if every element under a ships index has a 1 in that third element its a sink, otherwise just a hit (or miss if all indexes are 0).

-

Code Wars Kata can be really fun - and really frustrating. Sometimes when you have a bug you don't even get an error log to help you out! My advice is this, if you cannot find the problem in your own code - you've made it too complicated. If you stuck, write out sudo code for the problem and see if you can come up with a different way to approach it.

Hopefully you can learn something from what I did, good luck completing this challenge!

Comment: haha yes they are super fun! your solution is awesome too lol! i can totally see how using the dictionary could make a much more efficient solution. 

now that i know i can check the test cases using print(args) i should be able to solve many more kata in the future. i definitely feel like i am learning a lot doing this and i really appreciate your help. 

i am going to go ahead and leave this one where it is for today, do another tomorrow, and once i've solved that i will return to this problem fresh and implement the solution you suggested from scratch. thank you so much for the help!!!